# Copy the whole table content from one table to another one with the same columns names and number

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a CVS document (source_data.csv) in which I add data every month, I have uploaded it into PostGIS as a table (source_data), so I am trying to update this table by uploading the updated file (source_data1.csv) with more data. Uploaded as source_data1 table, So I am  inserting all from source_data1 to source_data

using this command:

```
INSERT INTO source_data
SELECT * FROM source_data1;
```

And it is giving me this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
> LINE 2: SELECT * FROM source_data1; 
>                ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 32
> ```

However, I can not rewrite all the column's name since they are many!

Comment: "*can not rewrite all the column's name*" - but that's your only option (and it's good coding style anyway)

Comment: And just about any SQL editor will generate a `SELECT` column list for you that you can copy and paste into your `INSERT` script.

Comment: And even if your editor doesn't generate the statement, it wouldn't be too hard to do yourself by querying `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: If the tables actually had the same column number, you wouldn't be having this problem in the first place.